# How to display error message in triggers (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a trigger that will prevent a user from booking a session on a date which has passed(Example: If todays date is August 23rd 2018, he can't book a date on August 22nd 2018)

In MySQL Workbench i managed to do it this way:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER checkDate
BEFORE INSERT ON ordination.session
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.session_date<CURDATE()) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Can not book a session on a date which has passed';
END IF;
END;
$$
```

I would like that same trigger to work in phpmyadmin. Unfortunately this one doesn't since i get a lot of errors that point me to the mysql manual. Could someone please help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the errors you are seeing phpmyadmin?

Comment: Use `SELECT VERSION()` chance is you might be using MariaDB without you knowing. MariaDB is a MySQL fork with some exceptions like supporting  `CHECK` constraints ( https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/ )  so you can use a check constraint instead off using a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big mistake on my part. I was constantly pasting the code in the wrong part of phpmyadmin. Instead of using "Triggers" section in the upper navigation bar, I should've used the "SQL" section and pasted the code there. When i pasted the code in this area, it worked perfectly. This solved my problem.